# Converting timezone using pytz

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone, utc, pytz

I have converted a timezone to 'Europe/London' which prints out:
2017-07-27 12:39:07+01:00
as London time which is correct.

But how to I get this to print the time with that +01:00 added onto it so it would be 13.39.07 in this case?
This is the function I am using:

```
def utc_to_london(utc_dt):
        tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London').localize(utc_dt)
        print(tz)
        return tz;
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

12:39:07+01:00 means "39 minutes past noon in a time zone one hour later than UTC."  So it means 11:39 UTC.

There is no circumstance in which it makes sense to "apply" the +1 forward to get 13:39, because that is a nonsensical timezone--you're "doubling" your UTC offset which has no practical meaning.

Comment: The only thing is that 12.39.07 is the utc time now

Comment: It sounds like your problem is that you're taking `12:39:07` and using `tz_localize()` to attach the London time zone to it.  Instead, what you need to do is "localize" it to `pytz.utc` then *convert* it to London time.